Android App crashes when rendering PDF with Android Pdf Viewer
My app code is below.
pdfView.fromFile(File(pdfPath))
.pages(0)
.enableSwipe(false)
.swipeHorizontal(false)
.enableDoubletap(false)
.defaultPage(0)
.enableAnnotationRendering(true)
.password(null)
.scrollHandle(null)
.enableAntialiasing(false)
.onError(OnErrorListener {
    // error handling
})
.load()

It seems like there is some problem with the annotation because it doesn't crash when enableAnnotationRendering(false).
Also, some PDFs crash and some don't.
PDFs edited on Windows or Android do not crash, but PDFs edited on Mac or iPhone do crash.
I suspect that rendering is failing due to missing fonts, but is there a possibility that the app will crash if there are no fonts?
Also, even if rendering fails, it cannot be caught with onError().
What can I do to prevent the app from crashing?
Thing you want to do

Catch rendering failures with onError() or another method to avoid crashing the app.
1 is completed, and I want to change it to the device's default font if the font does not exist.


If there's a crash, post the full stack trace.  We're not going to guess why it crashed when you can tell us.

Logcat only outputs the following:
2024-05-23 13:42:52.076 24665-24808 libc xxxxxxx A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 24808 (PDF renderer), pid 24665 (xxxxxxx )

There should be a bit more than that, including the library that it was in.  But I can tell you that's a dereference of a null pointer in C code, likely in the pdf library.  Either you're passing the library a null pointer and it isn't checking, you're not passing it something it expects you to pass, or the library itself has a bug.

Also-  that library hasn't had an update in github in over 5 years.  I really would not trust a library not under active development to work well after all that time.  And I'd be very worried about security problems, PDF viewers frequently have security issues.  If someone isn't working on patching them, I would not use it.

thank you.
I would like to consider changing to another library.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Using PDFBox (TomRoush), the crash no longer occurs using the following two methods.
The first method is to set AcroForm's needAppearance to false.
The modified code is below.
val document = PDDocument.load(File(pdfPath))
val form = document.documentCatalog.acroForm
if(form != null) {
   form.needAppearances = false
}
document.save(pdfPath)
document.close()

The second method is to obtain PDAnnotation and specify a different font for the font (COSName.DA).
The modified code is below.
PDDocument.load(File(pdfPath)).use { document ->
  val annotations = arrayListOf<PDAnnotation>()
  val page = document.pages[0]
    for (annotation in page.annotations) {
      if (annotation.subtype == PDAnnotationWidget.SUB_TYPE) {
        var cosObject = annotation.cosObject
        cosObject.setString(COSName.DA, PDType1Font.HELVETICA.baseFont)
        annotations.add(annotation)
      }
    }
  page.annotations = annotations
  document.save(pdfPath)
}

